# Store and retrieve metadata about Python distributions

Tags: python, setuptools

I am building a system which accepts plugins, using setuptools' entry_points functionality to find the plugins.  Plugins are thus supplied by distributions, but a single distribution may supply multiple plugins.

I want some way to encode metadata about each *distribution* which supplies one or more plugins.  Simple stuff like a bug-filing URL, but a little more than the built-in `setup` arguments allow.  As an added wrinkle, plugins use namespace packages, so there's no unique top-level package per distribution.

I've tried [using a setuptools extension via `egg_info.writers`](https://github.com/mozilla/build-relengapi/pull/44), but that exposes a setuptools bug and anyway has some chicken-and-egg problems.  I've also tried [putting the metadata in `setup.cfg`](https://github.com/mozilla/build-relengapi/pull/169) and reading it via `pkg_resources.resource_stream`, but realized too late that `setup.cfg` goes away once a package is installed.

I can probably dream up a few more esoteric or non-functional ideas, but I hope there's some kind of best practice (or even "least-awful practice") that I can follow.

Comment: Do you want this metadata to be accessible from Python code, or just sitting in a file somewhere with the installed package?

Comment: Accessible from Python code, but I don't mind opening and reading a file to accomplish that.  Just as long as the filename is determined portably -- so a hard-coded `/tmp/relengapi-metadata.ini` is out!

Comment: You can use `pkg_resources.resource_stream` (or `resource_filename()` etc.) for any file that's part of your distribution, so not just `setup.cfg`.

Comment: Yes, so I could, for example, instruct plugin developers to write a `DISTNAME-metadata.ini` file to the install prefix.  But is there a better way?

Comment: Another option is to add an additional entry point that just names a data structure.  That might be a little cleaner and more discoverable (and easier to set up with MANIFEST.in and all that jazz) than magic filenames installed in magic directories.

Comment: I have *a* solution in https://github.com/mozilla/build-relengapi/pull/172 - using an additional entry point group to locate dictionaries, which plugin dists can bury at whatever Python path they like (including inside their package in the namespace packages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most stable, reliable portion of setuptools appears to be entry_points.

The solution I adopted involves using an additional entry point group to locate dictionaries, which plugin dists can bury at whatever Python path they like (including inside their package in the namespace packages).  Then the system simply looks for those entry points and grabs the dictionary.